# How can I see the output of various Stan/RStan operations without model fitting?

Tags: r, stan, rstan

Stan has many different operations that can be used with arrays, matrices, and mixed data types. For example, [here are the mixed operations](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_29/functions-reference/mixed-operations.html). However, sometimes I am not sure whether an operation accomplishes what I believe it does and want to see what it produces very quickly.

For example, supposing I have a vector, I might want to see what happens when I pass it to the `diag_matrix()` function. While the [documentation](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_29/functions-reference/diagonal-matrix-functions.html) states this returns "The diagonal matrix with diagonal x," it can be helpful sometimes to take a look at this output during model development. Ideally, this could be done in the Stan program or in R itself, with pseudocode below.

Is there some way of accomplishing this, perhaps printing to the console?

#### R Example

```r
x <- vector(5)
diag_matrix(x)
# diagonal matrix here, only once!
```

#### Stan Example

```
vector[K] x;
diag_matrix(x)
# diagonal matrix here, only once!
```

Comment: What prevents you from creating a synthetic vector (one that you fill yourself), calling the operations and then printing the result to standard output? Stan will only 'fit' a model if it actually calls functions that need that model.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, if you can add an example then I'll accept.

Comment: Something like: `x<-(1,2,3)` followed by `M <- diag_matrix(x)` and `print(M)` (i'm not proficient with R)